# Is there any reson to not reduce Ping Maximum Response Time in IIS 7

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

IIS includes a worker process health check "ping" function that pings worker processes every 90 seconds by default and recycles them if they don't respond.  I have an application that is chronically putting app pools into a bad state and I'm curious if there is any reason not to lower this time to force IIS to recycle a failed worker process quicker.  Searching the web all I can find is people that are increasing the time to allow for debugging.  It seems like 90 seconds is far to high for a web application, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the obvious answer is that in some situations requests would take longer than 90 seconds for the worker process to return. If you can't imagine a situation where this would be appropriate, then feel free to lower it.

I wouldn't recommend going too much lower than 30 seconds. I can see situations where you get in recycle loops. However you can do testing and see what makes sense in your situation. I would recommend [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home) for load testing to see how your application behaves.